# Minimal Information on a Node to Describe a Tree's Structure

Tags: c++, data-structures, tree, nodes, graph-theory

*My question is this: what is the minimum amount of information I need to describe the relationships among the nodes to enforce a structure on a tree?  How can these rules be concisely represented?*

I have a tree data structure (in C++, if it matters to anyone.  A std::vector of std::vectors with pointers back up to the parents.).  Nodes can be specialized.  When a node is specialized, it may only be "valid" given that it has certain parents or may only be valid when it has certain children.  The system doesn't have 100% knowledge of all the various node types (that is, a user to build a plugin with new nodes and those nodes could have new rules).  While everything works well, it relies on our a-priori knowledge of how to construct a tree.  (A new user could place nodes somewhere that made no sense logically, and that is something we want to detect and prevent.)

We want to be able to "enforce" a valid structure.  Allow some nodes to be attached anywhere, while others have special places, etc.  All nodes, of course, inherit from a common base class and have a list of all of their children and a pointer to their parent.  Pretty simple.

My first attempt was to simply allow nodes to list their valid parent types.  This, however, lead to some nodes being very promiscuous and attaching themselves to parents where it simply didn't make sense.  To address this, I added a list of child types that a node could accept.  This worked well at pairing the tree down, but made management harder and, given the multiple levels of inheritance some nodes would have, difficult to mask out some types of children while allowing others.

At this point, I thought it worth while to ask the question.  Trees aren't my specialty...and certainly someone knows a well-defined way to construct such a tree and enforce relationships in a flexible and meaningful way.  Thoughts or ideas?

Other information, if it matters:  The structure tends to be very wide (hundreds to thousands of nodes) and shallow (2-10 levels deep).  There tends to be a root with between one and five sub-trees...which is where the real work begins.  I'm happy to use STL, Boost, or any other library which might help here.  I don't want to reinvent the tree.  Being able to represent the relationships among the nodes in order to construct the tree is the focus of the question.

Comment: Why not show the code you have done so far and use the code to explain your problem? For instance it is difficult to understand what you mean by `some nodes would have, difficult to mask out some types of children`

Comment: Depends on the kind of tree.  A tree with pages of nodes has different requirements than a simple binary tree.

Comment: Can you use `std::map` instead of writing your own tree?

Comment: "writing" the tree is not an issue.  Describing the valid structure of a tree from information on its nodes, independent of implementation, is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your issue is that you want to have one or more relationships between nodes.

The simplest method is to have one link for each *kind of* relationship.  If you want to traverse in two directions (forward and backward) in a relationship, you will need to have two links for each relationship.

If you want to have dynamic relationships, I suggest each node having a `map`, `std::map<relation, link>`.  The first item, the key, would be an enumerated relationship identifier (or `std::string`).  The value would be the link to the node.  This would allow you to say something like:

```
next_node = node_links[NEXT_BY_ALPHABETICAL];
```

I suggest you *draw* the relationships between your objects.  Also *draw* the tree and the relationships between the nodes.

Another alternative is to have separate trees, one for each relationship.  Each node in these trees would contain a pointer to the data item.  Thus only one data item exist; but there may be one or more indexing (relationship) pointers.

Finally, you may want to consider using a database, probably a *relational* database.

Comment: I can't use a proper database, but the idea of managing forward and backward relationships is interesting.  I don't think I can enumerate the relationships, however.  There are theoretically an unlimited number of types of nodes and relationships.  Are there any good authoritative references on tree design I could study?